# How can i manage all selectbox when onchange in any one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have listing week days on my web page and every day have a select box as like below

```
<select name="day1" >
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<select name="day2" >
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<select name="day3" >
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
.
.
.
.
```

Here if i select any option from "day2" then how can i make all others select box value default or null, as well as if i select with "day1" then day2 and day3 should be default or null using jQuery

Comment: `others select box value null` What do you mean? Making any other select element disabled or set as default value or what? Couldn't you use radio buttons instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `change` listener on all `select` and change every element what is `not()` itself.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
    $("select").not(this).val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="day1">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select name="day2">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select name="day3">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, i really appreciate you